# Clarification on output of insertion sort implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, insertion-sort

I was hoping for a clarification on the insertion sort algorithm implemented in Python. I am implementing the algorithm using this pseudo-code as a guide:

[image: image of pseudo-code]

Using the implementation exactly as below (replacing index `2` in `for` loop for python index starting at `0`):

```
l = [31, 41, 59, 26, 41, 58]
for j in range(1, len(l)):
    key = l[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0 and l[i] > key:
        l[i+1] = l[i]
        i = i - 1
    l[i+1] = key

print(l)

>> [31, 26, 41, 41, 58, 59]
```

As you can see it sorted all values other than the value at position zero in the list.

However if I alter the index conditional in the while loop from `i > 0` to `i >= 0` the list is ordered correctly on output:

```
l = [31, 41, 59, 26, 41, 58]
for j in range(1, len(l)):
    key = l[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i >= 0 and l[i] > key:
        l[i+1] = l[i]
        i = i - 1
    l[i+1] = key


print(l)
>> [26, 31, 41, 41, 58, 59]
```

Could someone please clarify why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remembered to subtract 1 from the index because Python's lists are zero-based in `for j`. You forgot to do the same in `while i > 0`. Replacing `while i > 0` to `while i >= 0` is the same as `while i > -1`

Comment: Thank you, you're absolutely correct - I completely missed this point I appreciate the concise response.